# Style problems with android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am learning Android programing, but making one exercise i get a problem.

The Excersice is that i need to do is work with styles, So i update the `res/values/style.xml` file with:

```
<resources>  
    <style name="ButtonStyle" >
    <item name="android:layout_width" >fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height" >wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor" >#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:gravity" >center</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle" >bold</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor" >#000000</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And i update the main file with:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:text="@string/Arrancar" 
        android:style="@style/ButtonStyle" />
```

But i get the error:

`No resource identifier found attribute 'style' in package 'Android'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `android:` prefix from your `style` attribute:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:text="@string/Arrancar" 
    style="@style/ButtonStyle" />
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. i'm sorry for the newbie question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no android prefix for style......You need to use  like this

```
style="@style/ButtonStyle"
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove Android prefix.....style attribute don't have a android prefix use this

```
 style="@style/ButtonStyle"
```